# How to enable drag and drop for an elevated MFC application using COleDropTarget

Tags: mfc, uac

I see there is a way to the enable drag and drop for elevatd MFC application using WM_DROPFILES, but need guidance on application that uses COleDropTarget.

Answer (score 3):

You must tell Windows that your elevated application accepts certain messages from non-elevated ones!

```
ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);
ChangeWindowMessageFilter(WM_COPYDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
ChangeWindowMessageFilter(0x0049, MSGFLT_ADD);
```

As described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/thread/2fa935cf-be57-4bcc-9b96-7ee5a6b2b7a5/).

Comment: Tried the trick with but it seems not working with COleDropTarget.

Comment: Well, there is no other way. Maybe you have to add additional messages to your filter? Check your code or use Spy++ to find those messages.

Comment: Is there any work around for COleDropTarget? The code project reference article by pac is also not working under elevated mode and COleDropTarget.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution in my project and it worked:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/840/How-to-Implement-Drag-and-Drop-Between-Your-Progra